# Nvidia-smi has failed because it couldn't communicate with the Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, updates, graphics

After replacing the GPU, I have upgraded my ubuntu to 20.04.1 LTS (a bumpy upgrade, it does not reboot normally, etc, a different problem)

Anyway, I am trying to update the nvidia driver. but somehow `nvidia-smi` does not communicate with the driver and it gives me the error:

```
Nvidia-smi has failed because it couldn't communicate with the Nvidia driver
```

I have done the following:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices

vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
model: GP102 [GeFOrce GTX 1080 Ti]
....
driver : nvidia-driver-450 -distro non-free recommended
```

also

```
  lspci -vnn |grep VGA
   lscpi : unable to loac libkmod resources error -12
    65:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Gp102 [GeForce GTS 1080 Ti] [10de:1b06] (rev a1) (prog-iff 00 [VGA Controller]

sudo apt install build-essential liblvnd-dev pkg-config
already the newest version

sudo hwinfo --gfxcard --short
graphics card:
    nVidia GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
Primary display adapter: #51
```

You can see that the card is there. However graphically when checking Settings->About the Graphics say `"llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0 256 bitys)` so it does not recognize the card.

Also graphically in Software & Updates, in Additional drivers I can see

```
NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
This device is using the recommended driver
Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-450 (proprietary tested 
1 proprietary driver in use
```

So it seems it is installed.

But when calling Nvidia X Server , the windows is completely empty.

How can I make my machine recognize the driver and the card?

P.S
Also following the advice of nvidia forum I did

```
grep nvidia /etc/modprobe.d/* /lib/modprobe.d/*
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf:blacklist nvidiafb
```

Also I did

```
nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available syste,
G_IS_OBJECT (object ) failed
```

Comment: Try disabling `Secure Boot` in your BIOS.

Comment: secure boot is disabled